# Extracting the function and arguments from a coroutine

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.6

Is it possible to extract the function and arguments of a coroutine object in python3.6?

Context: currently I have something like this:

```
async def func(*args):
    ...

ret = await remotely(func, x, y)
```

Under the hood, `remotely` pickles `func`, `x`, and `y`, scp's that to a different server, where it unpickles them, executes `func(x,y)`, pickles the result, scp's that back, and finally unpickles it into `ret`.

This API feels distasteful to me, I'd prefer to have:

```
ret = await remotely(func(x, y))
```

I could do this if I could pickle the coroutine object represented by `func(x, y)`, but when I tried that, I get:

```
TypeError: can't pickle coroutine objects
```

So my alternate hope is that I can extract `f`, `x`, and `y` from `f(x, y)`, hence this question.

Comment: What's wrong with `remotely(func, x, y)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So when you do `ret = await remotely(func(x, y))`, you actually construct the coroutine object for `func`. Fortunately, you can extract the information you need from coroutine objects, which you can send over for remote execution.

So first of all you can get the function name using the [`__qualname__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/) attribute. This will give you the fully qualified name, i.e. if the coroutine is nested, it will get you the full path to your function.

Next, you can extract the argument values from the frame object of the coroutine.

So this is how your `remote` function would look like

```
async def remote(cr):
    # Get the function name
    fname = cr.__qualname__

    # Get the argument values
    frame = cr.cr_frame
    args = frame.f_locals  # dict object

    result = await ...  # your scp stuff

    return result
```

---

There is just one caveat. You should indicate that the function should be only used the way that you have posted, i.e.

```
ret = await remotely(func(x, y))
```

...in other words, the coroutine should be "fresh", and not half-way executed (which is almost not possible if you initiate it right before passing it to `remote`). Otherwise, the `f_locals` value might include any other local variable that is defined before any `await`s.

Comment: Thank you for this. My colleague actually managed to solve the problem shortly after my post, and hacked up the `dill` source so that we can directly pickle coroutine objects. He independently came up with the same technique as you for getting argument values, but came up with a different technique to get the function without `__qualname__`.

Comment: Glad you got it solved. Maybe you should post the working solution as a separate answer?

Comment: @dshin I'm in searches for solution of the same problem (ans I had the same purpose to have nicer interface for defining functions sent to other processes). Dill can't dump coroutine object - I've tried. Can you post your approach somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Found no clean solution. But we can find function as a referrer to coroutine's code object:

```py
import gc
import inspect

def get_function_from_coroutine(coroutine: Coroutine) -> Callable:
    referrers = gc.get_referrers(coroutine.cr_code)
    return next(filter(lambda ref: inspect.isfunction(ref), referrers))

def get_kwargs_from_coroutine(coroutine: Coroutine) -> dict[str, Any]:
    return coroutine.cr_frame.f_locals

async def foo(a: str, b: int):
    return a * b

coro = foo("test", b=2)
print(get_function_from_coroutine(coro))  # <function foo at 0x7ff61ece9820>
print(get_kwargs_from_coroutine(coro))  # {'a': 'test', 'b': 2}
```